# How to assign background-position as something like 'margin-right: 10px'?

Tags: html, css, image, background-position

I am trying to put an image as the background and would like it to align to the right, but not closely align to. Something like margin-right:10px. Is it possible to do that in pure css, without explicitly adding a margin to the image?

I had several attempts, but all failed... 
http://jsfiddle.net/cA7Un/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently there's a proposal for extensions to `background-position` in the [CSS3 backgrounds module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) that addresses this, except — wait for it — nobody has implemented it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the example you put on jsfiddle:

I declared the following extra style:

```
.rss
    {
        background-image: url('http://tipabsorb.com/index/wp-content/plugins/category-specific-rss-feed-menu/rss_small_icon.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: right;
        width: 16px;
        min-width: 16px;
        max-width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        min-height: 16px;
        max-height: 16px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

This uses the same image, but adds an extra div to your your markup. This method gives you the image as a background image, and then with the margin you can position it as far from which ever side you want (by also changing the float if you want it on left hand side).

```
<div class='test' style='width: 300px; height: 100%'>
    <div class="rss">
    </div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

The positioning of the "rss" div before you normal markup is important as this affects the flow. Could also do it by positioning the div absolutely with a relative parent.

Finally I deleted the background from the ".test" class, as it has now been moved to the "rss" class.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a percentage, but this is only good if you know the width of the container will stay the same:

```
background-position: 95% center;
```

Otherwise, you could add 10 pixels of whitespace to the right of your image in an image editor like Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: thank you, thats quite close... but the result is not what I expect.. the image is not neat across elements

Comment: background-position:url(..image...) no-repeat 100% center; I think this is the better approach then as you said, leave a 10px on the right side of the png image and will do the trick, clever.